# cv2.createTrackbar call-back function

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have simple program for creating trackbar using cv2 and python 3.7. I am using a callback function that prints the trackbar value. The issue is, it prints the (same) value twice. Why is that?

```py
import cv2

def print_value(x):
    print(x)

cv2.namedWindow('Tracking', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.createTrackbar('Value', 'Tracking', 0, 255, print_value)

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) 

    if key == 27: # ESC key to quit
        break 

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I just want one value to be printed out. Preferably the one of the new position. Thanks...